# How to test autodiscovery with just one computer?

Tags: server, kotlin

I'm trying to write a Kotlin server with auto discovery, however I only have one computer to develop. My server uses a port and I just can't figure it out myself how to successfully test my application. Thanks for your help!

Comment: VMs or different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JVMs

You may be able to run copies of the app in different JVMs, but would have to run them on different ports.

## VMs

This may be slow, but may be an option

## Docker

Using Docker (and optionally compose) you been run multiple copies of the app on the same port, with less overhead than using full VMs.